# NodeJS, how do I input an integer as hex to a buffer

Tags: node.js, buffer, fs

I am seeking to open an existing HEX file into a buffer and make changes to it's content,
I am creating the buffer as so

```
const fs = require('fs');
var fileData = fs.readFileSync('./server/recipeTemplate/GemTwin.REL');
```

and I know if i want to put ascii characters as hex in I can use char codes such as this:

```
var recipeName = req.body.name
var recipeIndex = 2343;
for (var i = 0; i < recipeName.length; i++) {
    fileData[recipeIndex+i] = recipeName.charCodeAt(i);
}
```

the question is how do i do it for an integer,

I have unsuccessfully tried the following

```
fileData[2365] = (12).toString(16);
```

which resulted in 0 even though (12).toString(16) evaluates to C

How do I get the integer into an acceptable value for the buffer?

Comment: An int is an acceptable value for a buffer. Does `fileData[2365] = 12` not work?

Comment: i need it as hex so 0C, 12 would put 12 into the buffer position

Comment: No, you don't need it as hex. JS doesn't differentiate between decimals and hexes. They are stored as numbers. 0x... is just a different way to write a number.

Answer (score 0):

As [the documentation](https://nodejs.org/api/buffer.html#buffer_buf_index) explains, buffer values are unsigned 8-bit integers, i.e. numbers between 0 and 255.

It should be:

```
fileData[2365] = 12
```

> and I know if i want to put ascii characters as hex in I can use char codes such as this

There's no special data type for hex in JavaScript, `charCodeAt` returns an integer. The code in the question already does the same thing as above.

Answer (score 0):

Managed to achieve the desired results by setting the index equal to 0x[hexadecimal]